# Jquery Category abd subcategory Nested Drop Downs

Tags: jquery

I have 2 drop downs in Asp.Net MVC3.

1. Controller gives list of categories and I am using a Jquery Ajax call to controller category method and populating list of categories in dropdown list.
2. Controller gives list of subcategories and I am using a Jquery Ajax call to controller subcategory method and populating list of subcategories in dropdown list.

How do I populate su7bcategories based on selected category using jquery ? any help would be appreciated.

Also suggest me if there is any other alternate option to do this task.

Answer (score 1):

Attach onchange event with category and send the selected index of category to server. The server method should fill the subcategories in other dropdown

Comment: Could You please suggest me some example online. I am using plain html code for controls. I tried searching online but couldnt find one with pure html controls. every one uses html helpers and asp.net server controls which I dont want to use.

Comment: There are many ways provided here please go through it.  http://forums.asp.net/t/1468612.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Category
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="Category"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Subcategory
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="SubCategory"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ControllerName/GetAllCategory', type: 'Get', dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var categoryObj = $('#Category');
                categoryObj.empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, entity) {
                    categoryObj.append('<option value="' + entity.Id + '">' + entity.Name + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });

        $('#Category').change(function () {
            $('#SubCategory').empty();
            if ($(this).val() != null && $(this).val() != 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/ControllerName/GetAllSubCategory', type: 'Get', dataType: 'json',
                    data: { CategoryId: $(this).val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var subCategoryObj = $('#SubCategory');
                        //subCategoryObj.empty();
                        $.each(data, function (i, entity) {
                            subCategoryObj.append('<option value="' + entity.Id + '">' + entity.Name + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```